# laravel 5.2: php artisan vendor:publish not running

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hello anybody around to help me with this issue; I am running laravel 5.2 and everything works fine how ever after successfully updating my composer with 
`composer require pragmarx/tracker` and 
`composer require "geoip2/geoip2":"~2.0"`.

Publishing this two packages is really giving me a nightmare  when I run php artisan vendor:publish I get the following error

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
>     Class 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\ServiceProvider' not found

This is what I added in my service providers in the `/config/app.php`
`PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\ServiceProvider::class`,

And this is what I added to the aliases section in the same document
`'Tracker' => PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Facade::class`,

Somebody please help.

Comment: Check that `vendor/pragmarx/tracker/src/Vendor/Laravel/ServiceProvider.php` exists.

Answer (score 0):

run
`php artisan config:cache`
then run

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

Check if you find your new repo in the list of available providers

Answer (score -2):

In this case, the problem is most likely with the package **NameSpace issue**. However running `composer dump-autoload -o` might just work.